# How do I use Datasets with BigInts?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

Try as I may, I cannot create a Dataset of a case class with enough precision to handle a `DecimalType(38,0)`.

I've tried:

```
case class BigId(id: scala.math.BigInt)
```

This runs into an error in the `ExpressionEncoder` https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20341

I've tried:

```
case class BigId(id: java.math.BigDecimal)
```

But this runs into errors where the only possible precision is `DecimalType(38,18)`.  I've even created my custom encoder, borrowing liberally from the [spark source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.2/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/encoders/ExpressionEncoder.scala#L46). The biggest change is that I default the schema for `java.math.BigDecimal` to be `DecimalType(38,0)`. I couldn't find any reason to change the serializer or deserializer. When I provide my custom Encoder to [Dataset.as](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@as[U](implicitevidence$2:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[U]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U]) or [Dataset.map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@as[U](implicitevidence$2:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[U]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U]), I get the following stack trace:

```
User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot up cast `id` from decimal(38,0) to decimal(38,18) as it may truncate
The type path of the target object is:
- field (class: "java.math.BigDecimal", name: "id")
- root class: "BigId"
You can either add an explicit cast to the input data or choose a higher precision type of the field in the target object;
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot up cast `id` from decimal(38,0) to decimal(38,18) as it may truncate
The type path of the target object is:
- field (class: "java.math.BigDecimal", name: "id")
- root class: "BigId"
You can either add an explicit cast to the input data or choose a higher precision type of the field in the target object;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveUpCast$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveUpCast$$fail(Analyzer.scala:1998)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveUpCast$$anonfun$apply$34$$anonfun$applyOrElse$14.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:2020)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveUpCast$$anonfun$apply$34$$anonfun$applyOrElse$14.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:2015)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(TreeNode.scala:357)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionDown$1(QueryPlan.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$7.apply(QueryPlan.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsDown(QueryPlan.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressions(QueryPlan.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveUpCast$$anonfun$apply$34.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:2015)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveUpCast$$anonfun$apply$34.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:2011)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveUpCast$.apply(Analyzer.scala:2011)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveUpCast$.apply(Analyzer.scala:1996)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.resolveAndBind(ExpressionEncoder.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.as(Dataset.scala:359)
```

I can confirm that both my input `DataFrame.schema` and my `encoder.schema` have a precision of `DecimalType(38,0)`. I've also removed any `import spark.implicits._`, to confirm that the `DataFrame` methods are using my custom encoder.

At this point, it seems that the easiest option left is to pass the id around as a String. This seems wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

While I admire your gumption in defining a custom encoder, it is unnecessary. Your value is an ID--not something you intend to use *as a number*. In other words, you aren't going to use it for calculations. You are simply turning a `String` into a `BigId` for the sole purpose of perceived optimization.

As the legendary Donald Knuth once wrote: "*Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: **premature optimization is the root of all evil**.*"

So solve efficiency problems *when they actually happen*. Right now, you have a solution looking for a problem--and not even a working solution at that after spending a lot of time that should've been spent on the quality of your analytics.

As for the efficiency of using `String` as a general matter, rely instead on the [Tungsten optimizations](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/28/project-tungsten-bringing-spark-closer-to-bare-metal.html) the Spark team has worked very hard at under the hood, and keep your eye on the ball

Comment: Indeed.  At the time I started, storing the id as a `BigInt` didn't seem like a difficult problem. It appeared to be supported by Spark. Indeed, it works so long as I stick with untyped transformations (Basically the DataFrame API). It also seems that it's [not easy](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18484) to override the default precision and scale.

Comment: You remain focused on the difficulty of the task, which is the wrong focus. My point is that even if it were easy it is unnecessary. It would be a useful exercise if you needed  a number (as is the case with the JIRA issue you cite) and not a `String`. Meanwhile, don't you think if Spark needed to support `BigInt` (which it doesn't) because the thousands of people who have used Spark for analytics over the years needed it, they would've done so by now? And doesn't it strike you as a code smell to represent an ID as a `BigDecimal`?